# Is this question about Blu-Ray digital formats off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[**This**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/what-is-bluray-remux/2006#2006) asks about different digital formats, while not explicitly about how to play them, just the difference.

Would this type of question be on topic due to it relating to digital movie format or would it be better suited on another site, or would it be just *Off-Topic* in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this kind of question should be offtopic, here is why:

- It does not regard the analysis or content of any movie or show.
- It does not regard the production of a movie.
- It's a technical question (which is ok in general but,)
- the technical aspect it covers has no influence on the production or content of the movie.

I support technical questions like [How do they film scenes with the actors driving in a car?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/how-do-they-film-scenes-with-the-actors-driving-in-a-car) but this one only regards a technical aspect that has no influence on the movie itself.

I think the question runs along the lines of distribution questions, which are explicitly offtopic in the FAQ.

Also, if we allow this kind of technical question about bluray ripping we will open the door for more of those, like "What is better: DTS or AC3?" etc.

I would rather find questions on this site that are about the movies itself and their backgrounds than what happens with them once they are sold.

Comment: Agree, I'm trying to get a hold of SU mods to see if it might be a better fit for them.

Comment: Completely agree with this.

Comment: SU says no in current format but would rather we nuke it and user ask a new Q with a lot more detail and research and it would be viable.